# WSO2 DSS return zero instead of null for some of null fields

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

There is a service made on wso2 dss based on query on a mssql view, my problem is that the service returns 0 value for some of null fields in database. It seams that 0 just returns for numeric values for example for below elements with same null value in db, GPANO returns as 0 and GPA return as a null tag:

```
<element column="GPANO" name="GPANO" xsdType="xs:string"/>
<element column="GPA" name="GPA" xsdType="xs:string"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occurs when you have nullable numeric data types such as `tinyInt`, `Int`, ... in your database. So you should change your data service query like this:

```
select case when GPA is null then '' else GPA end as GPA, ...
```

This will solve your problem and you will not see 0 in your output.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in [WSO2 DSS 3.5.0](http://wso2.com/products/data-services-server/). you can use that distribution for your use case.